# Does the Internal Energy remain constant during Isothermal Process carrying Heat/Work interactions?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, energy-conservation

**- Scenario-1:**

Work is done on an insulated system then Change in Internal Energy will be..

del(E) = - W

**- Scenario-2:**

Work is done on the same system(diathermic in this case) but transferring some amount of heat to its surrounding then,
What will be the change in Internal Energy ?

Comment: conductive, non-insulated, Heat Interactive, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use the First Law of Thermodynamics,

$$dU=dQ+W.$$

In scenario 1, $dQ=0$ since the system is insulated, so $dU=W$, where $W$ is defined as the work done *on* the system and $dU$ is the corresponding change in internal energy.

In scenario 2, the system allows the passage of some heat, so $dQ$ is allowed to be nonzero (but still could be zero, i.e. for an adiabatic process). Here's where things get complicated. We can't actually say anything about the sign or magnitude of $dQ$ in general, since that depends on the particular way that work is done on the system (for an ideal gas, this refers to the particular path of the process in $PV$-space). As such, we cannot determine the value or sign of $dU$ in general.

However, if the system is an ideal gas or incompressible solid, and if we know the system's temperature is constant, then, since internal energy is proportional to temperature, $dU=0$ in this case.

Comment: if the temperature remained constant (Isothermal) in both scenario, will the energy change be constant ?

Comment: Internal energy is a function of temperature only, so $dU=0$ in that case.

Comment: So, if this comment is appended to the above scenario, will  dU = 0 ?

Comment: @ZaidAAmir See edited answer.

Comment: @probably_someone:  Who says that the internal energy is a function only of temperature?  This is true only for an ideal gas and an incompressible solid or liquid.

Comment: @ChestetMiller You're right. Edited to fix.

Comment: If seems to me that, if you know the work done on the surroundings W and you know the heat transferred to the system Q, then, from the first law, you know the change in internal energy.

Comment: @ChesterMiller But you don't in general know either of these things; even if you know the total work done, the particular path you take through phase space determines the heat transfer.

Comment: But the question stated that you know Q???

Comment: @ChesterMiller In scenario 1, we know Q is zero. But in scenario 2, we only know that Q is not necessarily zero. We don't know anything else about it, because such information depends on the particular path of the system through phase space.

Comment: That's not the way I interpret it.  But, in any event, the internal energy is not necessarily constant in an isothermal process.

Comment: @ChesterMiller I know, which is why I edited my answer to reflect that.